# Consolidate a list of Futures into a Map in Scala

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, option-type, future

I have two case classes `P(id: String, ...)` and `Q(id: String, ...)`, and two functions returning futures:

1. One that retrieves a list of objects given a list of id-s:
   `def retrieve(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[P]] = Future { ... }`

   The length of the result might be shorter than the input, if not all id-s were found.
2. One that further transforms `P` to some other type `Q`:
   `def transform(p: P): Future[Q] = Future { ... }`

What I would like in the end is, the following. Given `ids: Seq[String]`, calculate a `Future[Map[String, Option[Q]]]`.

Every `id` from `ids` should be a key in the map, with `id -> Some(q)` when it was retrieved successfully (ie. present in the result of `retrieve`) and also transformed successfully. Otherwise, the map should contain `id -> None` or `Empty`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there an `.id` property on `P` or `Q`? You would need one to create the map. Something like this?

```
for {
  ps <- retrieve(ids)
  qs <- Future.sequence(ps.map(p => transform(p))
} yield ids.map(id => id -> qs.find(_.id == id)).toMap
```

Keep in mind that `Map[String,Option[X]]` is usually not necessary, since if you have `Map[String,X]` the `.get` method on the map will give you an `Option[X]`.

Comment: Is it a linear search in `qs.find(...)`? ;)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, maybe `groupBy(_.id).map(_.head)` be more efficient? Don't know and not sure if it's it worth it.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco if you somehow manage to wrap it into `Some` and add `withDefaultValue(None)`, this might actually be an asymptotically more efficient one-liner solution, nice! :)

Comment: Thanks I ended up using a similar approach, as it is simpler and linear search was not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: Now assumes that `P` has a member `id` that equals the original `id`-String, otherwise the connection between `id`s and `p`s gets lost after `retrieve`.*

```
def consolidatedMap(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Map[String, Option[Q]]] = {
  for {
    ps <- retrieve(ids)
    qOpts <- Future.traverse(ps){
      p => transform(p).map(Option(_)).recover {
        // TODO: don't sweep `Throwable` under the 
        // rug in your real code
        case t: Throwable => None 
      }
    }
  } yield {
    val qMap = (ps.map(_.id) zip qOpts).toMap
    ids.map{ id => (id, qMap.getOrElse(id, None)) }.toMap
  }
}
```

Builds an intermediate `Map` from retrieved `P`s and transformed `Q`s, so that building of `ids`-to-`q-Options` map works in linear time.

Comment: From OP: "The length of the result might be shorter than the input", zip won't work in this case. That's why the id is necessary.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Hmm... `rIds` can be shorter than `ids`, that's true. That's what the remark after the first requirement says. But I zip `qs` with `rIds`. The `traverse` should return `qs` of same length as `rIds`, or fail completely.

Comment: `rIds` is of type `Seq[P]` not necessarily the same type as `ids`

Comment: What happens to `Future.traverse` if one of the `transform`-s fail?

Comment: @BKE Updated. Now it recovers from any failure with a `None`. That is: if some `p`s in the `Seq` fail to `transform`, the other `p`s in the `Seq` are not affected, but are mapped to `Some(_)`.

Comment: @BKE My question is "What should it do?". I would not like for code to lie to  me with None (No value found in DB for that key) while it swallows some exception ("badly formatted id?" etc)